# Change from Blue Card to Aufenthaltstitel in Germany

Tags: germany, working-visas, resident-permit, blue-card, residence-cards

I'm a non-EU citizen with a *Blue Card* (HR job) and my **contract ends in 6 months** (they have budget problems).  I started looking for different jobs, but I think that the **salary of some jobs that I find interesting may be slightly under the *Blue Card* minimum** requirement. If I get one of these jobs, could I **apply for the *Aufenthaltstitel* instead of the *Blue Card***? Does this reduce the possibility of the permit being approved?

Additional:

- I studied a master's in Germany
- My current contract is for 2 years. For the first 10 months I worked using the *job-seeking visa* you get after your studies, and I changed to the *Blue Card* 8 months ago.
- If I stay in my current job until the end of my contract, I would fulfill the requirements for the permanent residence, except for the "secure subsistence" which I have read means to have a contract valid for the near future or another income source (savings not counting); this is why I want to change jobs asap, to have a longer contract.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like in such situation, one probably can already apply for permanent residence permit irrespective of Blue Card, since one is eligible for permanent residence permit after 2 years of working (with Blue Card or without) after getting a degree in Germany, see https://service.berlin.de/dienstleistung/326558/en/. Even if one did not have a resident permit according to §18 all these 2 years, I can assume that very theoretically the time can be still counted, if the job conditions satisfied §18 conditions, [similarly to Blue Card regulation](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/20777/13223).

Also, with Blue Card itself, if one's job was satisfying the Blue Card conditions, one can get his/her 21 months counted from the beginning of the job contract.

For differences between Blue Card and "regular" residence permit, [see my other answer](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/a/11514/13223).

Finally, personally I do not think there should be any issues switching from Blue Card. However, you should ask Ausländerbehörde or lawyer to be sure.