# Niederlassungserlaubnis with my new offer letter and 3 month blue card salary?

Tags: germany

I have normal German residence permit (18 ABS). I have resided more than 33 months in Germany now. My company increased my salary to bluecard level. Is it possible for me to apply directly for a niederlassungserlaubnis with my NEW offer letter and 3 month blue card salary?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does the 21 months of period is calculated from the start of the Blue card application date or issued date for Niederlassungserlaubnis?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/does-the-21-months-of-period-is-calculated-from-the-start-of-the-blue-card-appli)

Comment: Also, with §18, one might be eligible for permanent residence permit after 4 years. If you are already about 3 years in Germany then just wait 6-9 more months (the Auslaenderbehoerde is anyhow still affected by COVID-19) and apply for the permanent residence permit a bit in advance, without getting Blue Card. They can accept the application before 4 years are over, since processing anyhow takes a couple of months.