# Do you really need to have passed the probationary period before applying for Permanent Residence in Germany?

Tags: germany, eu, blue-card

I am an EU Blue card holder working in Germany for 3 years now. I have passed the B1 German language exam and the Leben in Deutschland exam. I am transferring employers currently. Can I apply for Permanent Residence once I start with my next employer, even though I would still be on probationary status by then?

This is very different from this question: [Is the 21 month period calculated from the Blue card application date or the issue date for Niederlassungserlaubnis?](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/19377/is-the-21-month-period-calculated-from-the-blue-card-application-date-or-the-iss)

which was suggested as a possible answer below.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica, unfortunately, that is a very different concern.

Comment: @ouflak did you get pr? I am on probation period too and want to apply.

Comment: @AmitSingh, I only edited this question. I'm not the author. However they have been visiting this site recently, so hopefully they will be able to reply to your comment in due time.

Comment: @ineedhelp would be helpful if you can share your experience Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the officers at the Amt have large discretionary powers, and it is difficult to answer your question with certainty.

In principle, the only potential point of conflict would be where you have to "demonstrate financial independence" and ability to earn a livelihood. Nothing beats an unlimited work contract at that, of course after the probation. I have been refused PR when I applied with 6 months remaining on my contract at one location, but got approved at another location. So you see, it is best to ask your local Amt how they deal with these things there.

Practical advice: apply anyway. It is not that they process the application within a week. In my case they took 2-3 months, plus getting appointment already takes 2-3 months from place to place.